# Placing three DIVs inside of a parent side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. I have a parent DIV with a gray background (a row) with three child DIVs in it. Parent DIV width is 100% of the screen. Child A is a DIV, that is an image, and sets the entire rows height.

Child DIVs B and C split up the remainder of the row's width in half, and match the rows height. I can get it to where all of the DIVs get equal height but the child DIVs B and C do not fill up the remainder of the parents DIV.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: I'll post one once I get to a PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet with what I understand you are trying to do. (Also in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k0YCtKJvqfr2kGdnr2fS?p=preview).)

```css
.left{
  float: left;
  height: 120px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  }
.right{
  height: 60px;
  background-color: yellow; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="left">Div 1</div>
      <div class="right">Div 2</div>
      <div class="right">Div 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I made some changes but thank you for the great start.
http://plnkr.co/edit/dpMANcUW6CnBeOAK8fiC?p=preview